# Is access and modification of 'HTMLInputElement.<property>' faster than "Element.(g/s)etAttribute('<property>')"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For example, if I want to check if an input element is disabled what would be faster?

```
//assuming node is an <input> element
var a = node.getAttribute('disabled');
//or
var a = node.disabled;
```

Similarly, if I wanted to change the value,

```
//assuming node is an <input> element
node.setAttribute('disabled', true);
//or 
node.disabled = true;
//(Both change the DOM node)
```

Comment: `getAttribute` and properties are not equivalent, so even if you were to compare the speed it wouldn't give you an accurate result. `getAttribute` returns a string. `disabled` returns a boolean

Comment: How I thought about it, was that when you do `.(g/s)etAttribute` on an `HTMLInputElement` , it looks up all the way back to the `Element` ancestor, in order to call `.(g/s)etAttribute`, while `disabled` is a member of `HTMLInputElement` itself; so maybe it would be faster to just do `HTMLInputElement.<property>`.

Comment: props are way faster, for something that doesn't take very long either way... attributes have all sorts of extra considerations in the interface (namespace, encoding, etc), and there's the function call overhead and the inheritance resolution, and a few other things in-between the input and output that a simple property read doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

Native access is a fastest way because no compatibility navigator check is do.
In your case, disabled property is defined in famous navigator but an "special" event or property can be undefined.

So, if you want have fastest/performance solution, try to avoid framework property/event access and use an specific native script.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer correctly, but `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` are both native methods, and not added by some framework.

Comment: Woot ! You're right ! Indeed it's an native JS method ( my bad sorry ). But the case is same, call directly the property is more fastest than a method call because no verification/manipulation is done